# Are "Container" classes not pythonic?

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I want to use a mutable dictionary like object for passing data in between processes, but instead of using the built in dictionary type, I create an empty "Container" class, like so:

```
class Container(object):
  pass

x = Container()
x.a = 42
x.b = ['Hitch', 'Hiker']
```

Now, I can use `x.a` instead of writing out `x['a']`, which seems a bit clearer to me. Assuming I don't expect to be looping over the key values, are there any major disadvantages that I'm missing by using this "Container" vs. standard dictionaries?

Comment: For one thing, all of your keys need to be strings.  You can't say `x.[4, 5, 6] = 5`

Comment: @zondo I know what you mean, but lists can't be keys in dictionaries either.

Comment: @zondo - true, but as I'm trying to pass attributes between processes, so it's no different from not being able to do `self.5 = 5`

Comment: @nbubis Do you know about `namedtuple`?

Comment: @L3viathan - `namedtuple` is not mutable, as stated in the question.

Comment: I've done this often. It creates a new namespace for variables. Even though you loose key names such as `container['I have spaces!']` that's fine when you want "variable-looking" stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a perfectly pythonic thing to do. In fact it is [recommended in the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#odds-and-ends).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do that and still get the advantages of dictionaries, I would subclass `dict`:

```
class Container(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self[name]
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self[name] = value


x = Container()

x.a = 42
x.b = ['Hitch', 'Hiker']

print(x)
```

Prints:

```
{'b': ['Hitch', 'Hiker'], 'a': 42}
```

---

You might want to treat existing attributes seperately, so you can still change them:

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    if name not in dir(self):
        self[name] = value
    else:
        super().__setattr__(name, value)
```

Comment: Very nice. What's the purpose of the last bit you added?

Comment: If you call `dir` on a normal dictionary, you'll see all the methods and attributes it has. If you, at a later point, wanted to dynamically change the `copy` method, for example, it wouldn't work in the first version, because it would just put it in the normal dictionary storage. (Also it wouldn't be accessible, because `__getattr__` only gets called when the attribute is missing). In most cases, it won't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with doing that for quick, simple containers.  The main disadvantage is that you don't get all the other methods of dict (like `.get()`, `.items()`, etc.), and your keys have to be valid Python identifiers.

Note that there are also libraries providing similar functionality with more convenience features (such as [attrdict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/attrdict/2.0.0)).

Answer (score 1):

Quite the contrary; the `Namespace` class in the standard library's `argparse` module is essentially such a container (after you ignore a few magic and private methods for internal use).